# Silicon organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've heard that in some alien planet there might be life based on Silicon chemistry, but have we ever discovered molecules that are similiar to carbon organic compounds? Something like chains or rings...

P.S. I'm not asking if silicon-based life is possible, i'm just asking if there actually are silicon organic compounds(in the sense that they are similiar to their carbon counterparts)

Comment: Yes there **are** chains and rings of silicon, though they are quite totally different from their carbon counterparts. All in all, the question is way too broad to be answered.

Comment: @Ivan The OP's asking if molecular silicon rings/chains have been synthesized (Yep). Though the first line in the post seems to be asking, "Is silicon-based life possible?", the OP doesn't *explicitly* request that. So...not all that broad ;)

Comment: Some silicon based molecules are similar to the carbon analogs. However, the full richness of organic chemistry that we observe as necessary for life on Earth is not expressed in silicon-based chemistry, so silicon-based life is extremely unlikely.

Comment: This should be well suited in worldbuilding.SE.